# What data structure can I use to store and retrieve ranges of discrete values?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have a JavaScript program in which I will be managing a lot of ranges of integers. In this context, a range is simply a start and an end value (or anything equivalent, like a start and a length value), with a reference to another object. The ranges can overlap, and can be identical (although the referenced object will be different).

The possible start and end values are between 0 and 4294967295 (2<sup>32</sup> - 1 or `0xFFFFFFFF`), although there are several big "holes" in the domain that no range will ever cover, even partially. Most ranges will be very small compared to the domain of possibilities: I expect that the overwhelming majority will have a length smaller than 2000.

My most important use case for this structure will be to look up all ranges that contain a given integer value. Most of the time, I expect the lookup to fail (there will be no range containing the given value).

Otherwise, I will obviously also need to add elements to it (often) and delete elements from it (seldom). Once in a while, too, I'll need to find all ranges that overlap a given range, rather than all ranges that contain a single value.

What kind of data structure can I use for that? A linear search in a list of ranges is impractical because the lookups fail most of the time; and I need to do lookups very, very often.

Comment: Are the ranges bounded by 0 and max_int? Or -inf to inf?

Comment: What is a range? Is it simply a `[min, max]` pair?

Comment: @kojiro, yes, `[start, end]` or `[start, length]`, either would do.

Comment: What environment are you programming against? Must this work for old JS implementations that don't have a deterministic order for the properties of sparse arrays? </hint>

Comment: Also, can you eliminate identical ranges and ranges that fit entirely within another range?

Comment: @kojiro, I'm targeting browsers that support typed arrays and a few other recent features, so I suppose that this is not an issue. There can be no identical ranges (as the start property is always distinct), but I cannot delete ranges that fit entirely within another one.

Comment: Wait, scratch that. There *can* be identical ranges, although it should be very rare.

Comment: How many ranges are there? Is it in the order of thousands, millions, or should any number be possible (i.e., even billions)?

Comment: @pkr298, I'd expect a thousand or so.

Comment: What you want is called an **interval tree**.

Answer (score 1):

binary tree where the key is the start (low) value.  Once you find a key you can look wide (higher and lower) fairly easily.

Comment: Or a tree where each node has 16 children. It lends itself nicely to the range of the values.

Comment: Using a binary tree with the start key just helps me find the last range I need to test against, because any range whose `start` is lower than the value I'm looking for has the potential to have a far-enough `end` to match. In the average case, that would cut in half the number of elements I have to explore, but it's still not quite good enough.

Comment: My thinking is find the set with the lowest min that still includes the search key then look at sets with larger mins, collecting results, until you find the first set with a min that excludes the search key, does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You tell me to find the range with the smallest start such that it still contains the value, then search from there? If so, my whole problem is to find this first range in an efficient manner.

Comment: Upon further reflection I don't think a binary tree directly solves your problem but your solution is definitely tree based. I would look at either a segment tree [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree] or an interval tree [http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~jstewart/378notes/22intervals/].

Answer (score 0):

I like System.Tuple for something like this [or F# lists but few people know F#].

If the range is continuous that makes it simple to have the start and end integers as the tuple Tuple nums = (start, end), otherwise having the tuple with a start-end as the first entry of a tuple and the list as the second may work for you, Tuple nums = ((start, end), List).

Comment: It's very simple to store in Javascript too, as the syntax to create an array is very concise: `var nums = [start, end]`. As you may guess from that comment, though, that's not my concern. I'm looking for a way to find a range in a collection of ranges based on if it contains a value, and a linear search through all the ranges I manage will not cut it. Besides, I'm working in Javascript, so .NET classes are not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the start and end of all ranges in one list as a map back to the range index you can do it in order n. ie mylist = [ {45: range1}, {47: range2}, {55: range1}, {57:range2} ]
THen you can scan through the list and set a boolean true the first time you see a tag and false the second time you see it. when you find a number higher than yours you can tell which ranges you are inside. You can use bisect to insert O(logn), while deletes and inserts are O(n). Good Luck! ~Ben

Comment: Linear time is too expensive because I have a lot of ranges and very often the values I'm looking up aren't present, which is the worst-case scenario of a linear search.

Answer (score 0):

**ATTEMPT 1:**

Keep 2 binary trees, one for the start values and one for the end values. Have your nodes for both trees (or just the 'end') have a property referencing unique ranges by some id (the range's start value).

Do a binary search on the 'start' tree to narrow the list to the ranges where the start is less than or equal to your search value. Do the same on the 'end' tree where the value is greater than or equal to search value. Find the intersection of the nodes from both trees, and those ranges contain your search value.

You can find the intersection using a hash map/set for optimal performance.

**ATTEMPT 2:**

What if you kept a hash list for the intervals where the keys are the first however many bits that are shared by both the start and end values?

So, if start is '11001101' and end is '11010010', the key is '110'. Each key would map to a list of ranges (start and end) that share the key.

When searching for a value to see what ranges they are in, for example '00101111', you'd have to search the hash list for n different values or so, where n is the number of bits (32 in your case). In this case, you'd search for '00101111', '0010111', '001011', and so on. For each hit, you'd have to actually check that the search value is in the range.

At first sight, it looks to me that on average, for every hit you get, half will be false positives, but that shouldn't matter if the number of hits are small, and the larger the keys are the less hits it should get.

There is a slight problem for, say a start of '00101110' and end of '01100111' because the key would be '0' meaning there will be a significant number of 'false positives'. Better would be if there were 2 different keys, '001' and '01', although I'm not sure about the particular algorithm you'd need to code for this optimization. If the ranges are small enough and this problem can be solved or overlooked, then you can get very fast lookups as most keys will be relatively long and not match the searches.

Comment: Assuming the average case, where half the nodes start too far and half the nodes end too early, this pretty much executes in linear time since we have to deal with two halves.